# phpのビルトインサーバーに環境変数を指定して起動する方法

Tags: php, macos

開発環境や本番環境で設定を自動で切り替えるために`$_SERVER['ENVIRONMENT']`を読みこむようにしているのですが、`php -S localhost:8000`としてサーバーを立ち上げた時の環境変数を指定する方法がわかりません。

教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 同じ質問が本家にありました
[Setting environment variables with the built-in PHP web server - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784116/setting-environment-variables-with-the-built-in-php-web-server)